# TypeORM FindOperators with transformer

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I want to use my own custom transformer methods for marshalling / unmarshalling a data structure out of the database.

So my entity looks something like this:

```js
class EntityName {

  @Column({ type: `text`, transformer: { from: fromPostgres, to: toPostgres } })
  colName: CustomClass;

}
```

Then I obviously have a custom class, along these lines:

```js
class CustomClass {
  propertyA: string;
  propertyB: number;
}
```

And my mapping functions:

```js
fromPostgres(value: any) : any {
  let c = new CustomClass();
  c.propertyA = value.split(" ")[0];
  c.propertyB = parseInt(value.split(" ")[1]);
  return c;
}

toPostres(value: any) : any {
  return `${value.propertyA} ${value.propertyB}`
}
```

and so forth.  Obviously this is not the use-case but you get the idea.

So this all works great, no problem.  Except when you do a query with FindOperators.  You know, something like this:

```js
let c = new CustomClass();
c.propertyA = "a";
c.propertyB = 12;
getRepository(EntityName).find({where: { colName: LessThan(c) } });
```

When I inspect the toPostgres method, what I'm getting passed in there is the FindOperator object.  This has the underlying CustomClass instance stored in the _value property (accessible through the get value() getter).  This is all well and good, but I'm not sure how this gets parsed into the SQL, since whatever I write for the toPostgres method, like for example extracting out the .value and calling toPostgres on that, the SQL query generated does not do a less than query, it looks for a normal equal.

You know, you get something like this:

```sql
WHERE "EntityName"."colName" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["a 12"]
```

instead of what I want, which is:

```sql
WHERE "EntityName"."colName" < $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["a 12"]
```

So, am I going to have to implement the entire range of FindOperators for my custom class?  (I really hope not!). And if I do, how do I force what is presumably a higher-level function to modify the SQL query to be less than instead of equal.

OR, do I just modify the FindOperator somehow, by applying toPostgres to the value recursively and let the query builder do the rest.  This is my preference, but as far as I can tell _value is a private property so I'm unsure how to proceed with that line of thinking.

I was really hoping that TypeORM would be smart enough to continue to do whatever it already does with FindOperator and just apply the transformer function to the underlying value for me, but it doesn't seem to be the case unless there's some other configuration that I've missed?

Answer (score 6):

Ok so after several hours of reading through the code and how queries are assembled in TypeORM, I've come up with the following solution.

```js
toPostgres(value : any) : any {
    let returnValue = null;
    if(! value) {
      return null;
    } else if(value instanceof CustomClass) {
      returnValue = `${value.propertyA} ${value.propertyB}`;
    } else {
      let findValue = value as FindOperator<CustomClass>;
      returnValue = new FindOperator<CustomClass>( findValue[`_type`] as FindOperatorType, toPostgres(findValue.value), findValue.useParameter, findValue.multipleParameters)
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
```

In other words, I had to recursively apply the transformer function to the _value property of all FindOperators.

Comment: Your answer helped me immensely, thank you very much! :)

Comment: Very happy to hear it!

Comment: It's worth noting that if you do the recursive model you should use `._value` otherwise when you encounter things like `Not(In([a,b])` you won't be rebuilding the recrusive graph of Not and then In.  Typeorm unboxes `.value` to `[a,b]` if the parent is wrapped.