# IN operator does not seem to work with primary key fields

Tags: typeorm

Using MySQL.

I have the following entity:

```
import { Column, Entity, ValueTransformer } from 'typeorm';

const ormIdTransformer: ValueTransformer = {
  to: (value: any) => (value !== undefined && value !== null ? Number(value) : value),
  from: (value: any) => (value !== undefined && value !== null ? String(value) : undefined),
};

@Entity()
export class User {
  @Column({ type: 'int', transform: ormIdTransformer, primary: true })
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'int', transform: ormIdTransformer })
  profileId: string;

  // ...
}
```

Please note that `profileId` is not mapped as a relation here.

In my app, I have a custom `UserRepository`, and it has access to an `entityManager` (both internally, and externally, in case the operation is running inside a transaction).

I'm trying to search for all users that have specific IDs and a specific profile (also by ID):

```
// Just an example
const profileId = '1';
const userIds = ['1', '2', '3', /* ... */];

const ids = await entityManager.find(User, { where: { profileId, id: In(userIds) }, select: ['id'] });
```

I'd expect TypeORM to generate a query similar to the following:

```
SELECT `User`.`id` from `User` `User` WHERE `User`.`profileId` = ? AND `User`.`id` IN ?`
-- Parameters: [1, [1, 2, 3, ...]]
```

Instead, TypeORM seems to completely ignore the `FindOperator` (the `In`) I provided, and just passes `In(userIds)` through as if it was a normal value. This `FindOperator` goes directly to my `ValueTransformer`, which I think is not correct.

But that's not the worse of it. By activating query logging, I see that TypeORM generates the following query:

```
SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id` FROM `User` `User` WHERE `User`.`profileId` = ? AND `User`.`id` = ?
-- Parameters: [2, NaN]
```

The operation obviously fails with a database error: `QueryFailedError: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'where clause'`.

Notice how the condition for the `id` column is not being applied correctly: it should be `IN`, not `=`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you share the query getting executed on mysql.

Comment: The generated query is already in the question. But here it is: ```SELECT `User`.`id` AS `User_id` FROM `User` `User` WHERE `User`.`profileId` = ? AND `User`.`id` = ?
```

Comment: this query doesn't have IN clause.

Comment: Well, that's exactly my question. As you can read from my question, I used TypeORM's `In` operator, as per the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging, I found out that the problem was related to the custom transformer I was implementing for my IDs.

`QueryBuilder` has [special logic to take care of `FindOperator`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/123f7d6dde3fee5172a04afb9c015d9f7a74178e/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts#L875), but that only works if [`ColumnMetadata.getEntityValue`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/123f7d6dde3fee5172a04afb9c015d9f7a74178e/src/metadata/ColumnMetadata.ts#L580)  (which is called in `QueryBuilder`) actually returns an operator. But `ColumnMetadata.getEntityValue` lacks the logic to deal with `FindOperator`; instead of applying the transformation to the operator's wrapped value, it applies the transformation to the operator itself.

With that knowledge, I looked up for problems related to `FindOperator` and custom transformations, and found [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65639666). That helped me implement a transformation process that actually works with FindOperators.

Long story short, turns out I had to reconstruct the entire operator, and transform the values wrapped in it myself. This is what I came up with:

```
import { FindOperator, FindOperatorType, ValueTransformer } from 'typeorm';

const idFromDb = (value: any) => {
  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return String(value);
};

const idToDb = (value: any) => {
  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    return undefined;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map(idToDb);
  }
  if (value instanceof FindOperator) {
    return new FindOperator(
      value.type as FindOperatorType,
      idToDb(value.value),
      value.useParameter,
      value.multipleParameters,
    );
  }
  return Number(value);
};

export const ormIdTransformer: ValueTransformer = {
  to: idToDb,
  from: idFromDb,
};
```